# Azure IoT hub: How to get data for the device for last n days

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-iot-hub

Consider my devices are reporting a sensor data to iot hub every 30 seconds.
From my backend node.js server(Which is hosted on AWS) I want to get sensor data such that I can show to my users - current data, today's max, today's min, and weeks data's chart. I am able to get only current sensor data using the device twin. How can get data for last `n` days?

Answer (score 1):

For n maximum 7 days, see [Visual real-time sensor data from Azure IoT Hub using Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-live-data-visualization-in-power-bi), where the Stream Analytics Job can be started by your custom datetime.

or you can use the full solution for long-term storage: [Azure Time Series Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/propel-your-iot-platform-to-the-cloud-with-azure-time-series-insights/).

Comment: I read about time series and stream analytics but they are very expensive solutions

Comment: in this case, you can use an Azure IoT Hub custom endpoint to the storage and route the message there (cold path), see more details https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage

Comment: It uses blob storage but I did not find any documentation about how to do querying to fulfill my requirement.

Comment: the Azure Stream Analytics is the service for your requirements, have a look at it, the price is $0.11/hr per streaming unit. If you are looking for something "almost free", than you have to built yourself using for instance EventHubTrigger or BlobTrigger function + storage + ...

Comment: Oh oK. I misunderstood the pricing. I will try it.